# Is it possible to inject javascript event listeners to HoverProvider?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Is there a way to inject event listener or custom code to Monaco Hover Provider contents when `registerHoverProvider` function is called?

```js
    monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
      provideHover: function (model, position) {
        return {
          range: new monaco.Range(1, 1, model.getLineCount(), model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())),
          contents: [
            {
              isTrusted: true,
              supportHtml: true,
              // Use markdown or HTML to create a link and when 
              // that link is pressed, custom javascript code will be executed
              // with something like onclick="..."
              value: '<a onclick="code_here"> click me </a>'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
```

Here's the official example of hover events: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-hover-provider-example

Answer (score 0):

In this issue the devs says it's limited on few html elements but you can't add event handles...would like to know if there is some workaround for now I'm trying to use a custom popover but i'm struggling as to get the current hovered element.

https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/801#issuecomment-941791325